# VSTS fails with Visual Studio Build when net461 is referencing netstandard2.0

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

We're migrating a library project to `netstandard2.0` from `net461`. Some libraries doesn't support .NET Standard yet so the hosting application is runnning `net461` and are referencing our libraries that use `netstandard2.0`.

This works perfectly locally with Visual Studio 15.3 where everything runs and builds.

According to the Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) .NET Standard with SDK 2.0 implements 4.6.1 which I assume is why it works locally.

[image: .NET Standard support]

When running build in Visual Studio Online (VSTS) fails with multiple errors like:

> Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.0 is not compatible with net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

I read up on github discussions [here](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwiuiZGNy5_XAhXJCJoKHWtQDYoQFgg2MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Faspnet%2Fhome%2Fissues%2F2022&usg=AOvVaw2t3zdJ9RBHsKkm66yAodGX) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/home/issues/2022) that talks about similar problems being a tooling issue and added a `.NET 
Core Tool Installer` task to build that installs Core 2.0 but still with no luck.

What do I need to do to get build working in VSTS?

UPDATE:

(Changed title to Visual Studio Build instead of MS Build)

Found this thread https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/454 talking about the VSTS needing an update.

I'm running VS Enterprise 15.4.1, VSTS Build [is running version 15.3.5 today](https://github.com/adventworks/hosted-pool-images/blob/2017.10.01/vs2017-on-windows-2016/image.md) which is enough according to the issue on github. This is even more confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround by using `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build` with version `2.* (preview)` which works perfectly.

Instead of using MS Build or Visual Studio 2017 build, just replace the build tasks with the following `dotnet` tasks.

(If you don't have any private feeds you don't even need the `dotnet restore` command since `dotnet build` will restore packages for you).

TL;DR; use this instead:

[image: Working build tasks]